# utility::get_instance() should be compatible with & Singleton::get_instance()

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp

I tried to run an application but I got the error below, not sure what is it about, below are the files utitlity.php and domsecure.php

Strict Standards: Declaration of utility::get_instance() should be compatible with & Singleton::get_instance() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Citykites/core/utility.php on line 557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend a parent class, any children methods that override parent methods should have the same definition (ie be called in the same way).

Comment: Thank you! so this means :get_instance() in sigleton is not compatible ? shall I post the singleton too? Thanks again!!!

Comment: I think those are `WARNING` type messages, so the code will probably still work, but basically if you extend a parent class that has the method:
`function blah($something, $another) {...}`
and extend it in your child:
`function blah($different) {...}`
you'll get these sorts of warnings.

Comment: How to get rid of these warning? I am actually working on completely new code and its probably designed in codeignitor or cakephp. Actually I want to sort off the error rather than mute the warning! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I think you're getting those because your child functions don't have the reference operator `&` in the function definition.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, and my child class somehow was implementing the get_instance() method without the &.